# Making several tables with hasMany for a complex finding

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-many

I'm having trouble assembling the tables where I will search powers of attorney for several companies.

where:

Prosecutor will belong to several companies (X, Y, Z)
Companies have several branches (EU, Brazil, USA, etc ...)
The branches will have multiple units. (Energy, Oil, etc. ..)

The attorney will also have various powers (signing, trading, etc.).

**The intention is that in the end, I can find an attorney who is able, for example, to sign the contract by energy unit of Brazil subsidiary company X.**

Can someone help me with the and hasMany tables and with logic? Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code that you have already?

Comment: I don't have a code. I have no idea how to do it... :(

Comment: In that case I think you should read [associations with cake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) first. You already know how you want your models to link together (Prosecutor hasAndBelongsToMany Companies, Companies hasMany Branches, etc etc). If you don't even have the tables in the database, try at least to put an approximate of what you think it should be like so we can correct you. Again, you already know the associations, so the rest is reading how to link everything together and Cakephp documentation explains that really well.

Comment: If a `Company` can have more than one `Prosecutor` then the relation should be: `Prosecutor <--> HasAndBelongsToMany <--> Company`

Answer (score 1):

Just create those tables as usual and then you will have to create relational tables.

**`prosecutors_to_companies`** (they may belong to several companies, right?)

```
prosecutor_id | company_id
       1            2
       1            4
       2            6
```

Then create the next relational table: 
**`companies_to_branches`**

```
company_id | branch_id
      1         4
      1         3
```

Then with help of `JOINs` retrieve the needed data.

This example may help you - http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: In CakePHP conventions, the name of the join-tables should be `companies_prosecutors` and `branches_companies`. I.e. no *'to'* in the middle and the joined tables in alphabetical order. Also, if the join-tables will contain additional information, an `id` column (AutoNumber) should be present as CakePHP doesn't support combined PKs. Documentation can be found here: [Model and Database Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)